# Ordered tally of the cumulative number of unique words seen by a given position

Tags: python, list

I have a list of words given below (example):

```
['the', 'counter', 'starts', 'the', 'starts', 'for']
```

I want to process this list in order and generate a `pair (x,y)` where x is incremented with each word and y is incremented only when it sees a unique word. 
So for the given example, my output should be like:
 `[(1,1) (2,2), (3,3) (4,3) (5,3) (6,4)]`

I am not sure about how to do this in python. It would be great if i can get some insights on how to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? We do not write code for you on SO. Please read the [faq] and [ask].

Comment: I tried to create a dictionary and count the number of times each word appears. My dictionary returns ('for' :1) ('counter':1) ('the':2) ('starts' :2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> words = ['the', 'counter', 'starts', 'the', 'starts', 'for']
>>> uniq = set()
>>> result = []
>>> for i, word in enumerate(words, 1):
        uniq.add(word)
        result.append((i, len(uniq)))

>>> result
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 4)]
```

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
>>>from collections import Counter
>>>data = ['the', 'counter', 'starts', 'the', 'starts', 'for']
>>>tally=Counter()
>>>for elem in data:
>>>    tally[elem] += 1
>>>tally
Counter({'starts': 2, 'the': 2, 'counter': 1, 'for': 1})
```

from here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Of course, this results in a dictionary not a list. I wouldn't know if there's any way to convert this dict to a list (like some zip function ?)
Hope it might be any help for anyone

Comment: This is not how to use counter - it is acting as a simple defaultdict, the proper way is to pass the list into the Counter constructor and call a method such as Counter.items() to get the list of (element, count) pairs.

Comment: I think the example you provided is a bug in the documentation

Comment: FWIW, the ``tally[elem] += 1`` code is a correct use of ``Counter`` and corresponds exactly to how Guido originally described how the counter should behave.  That said, the commenter is correct in pointing out that it is simpler to just pass the input list into the Counter constructor.  The commenter is incorrect in comparing the counter to ``defaultdict(int)`` which has different characteristics (i.e. looking up an unknown key triggers a call to ``int()`` and inserts the ``0`` into the dictionary where as a ``Counter`` just calls *\_\_missing\_\_()* to return but not insert a zero).

Comment: A better comment would have been, "as presented, the code could be simplified; however, neither version answers the OP's actual about running tally of the number of unique elements seen at and to the left of a given position in the sequence.

Answer (score 6):

### Use `collections.Counter` for counting occurrences:

I appreciate this doesn't directly answer your question but it presents the canonical, pythonic way to count stuff as a response to [the incorrect usage provided in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15064516/1083707).

```
from collections import Counter
data = ['the', 'counter', 'starts', 'the', 'starts', 'for']
counter = Counter(data)
```

The result is a dict-like object that can be accessed via the keys

```
counter['the']
>>> 2
```

you can also call Counter.items() to generate an unordered list of (element, count) pairs

```
counter.items()
>>> [('starts', 2), ('the', 2), ('counter', 1), ('for', 1)]
```

The output you want is slightly weird, it might be worth re-thinking why you need the data in that format.

Comment: This is one of the only informed answers here. I can't upvote it enough.

Comment: @JesseDhillon The answer shows how to count the inputs; however, that is not the question the OP asked.  It is not even close!  The OP doesn't want a count, he wants to process the list in order and to emit pairs in the form ``(position, number_of_unique_values_seen_so_far)``.  The OP specified that the output should be: ``[(1,1) (2,2), (3,3) (4,3) (5,3) (6,4)]``.  This is a job for *set* not for *Counter*.

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> words = ['the', 'counter', 'starts', 'the', 'starts', 'for']
>>> for x, w in enumerate(words, 1):
...   seen.add(w)
...   print(x, len(seen))
...
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 3)
(4, 3)
(5, 3)
(6, 4)
```

In actual practice, I'd make a generator function to successively yield the tuples, instead of printing them:

```
def uniq_count(lst):
    seen = set()
    for w in lst:
        seen.add(w)
        yield len(seen)

counts = list(enumerate(uniq_count(words), 1))
```

Note here that I have also separated the logic of the two counts. Since `enumerate` does just what you need for the first number in each pair, it's easier just to handle the second number in the generator and let `enumerate` handle the first.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = ['the', 'counter', 'starts', 'the', 'starts', 'for']
print [(i, len(set(data[:i]))) for i, v in enumerate(data, 1)]
```

a dictionary mentioned in your comment is created as follows:

```
data = ['the', 'counter', 'starts', 'the', 'starts', 'for']
print {j: data.count(j) for j in set(data)}
```

Comment: In a similar fashion, but a bit shorter:

   res = [(data.count(w), w) for w in set(data)] yields 
    [(1, 'counter'), (2, 'the'), (2, 'starts'), (1, 'for')]